# Java Swing How to detect a list selection event

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling, jlist

I'm making a simple GUI where the user can select an item from a list of Strings using the `JList<String>` component, and I want my program to update a JTextField with some data describing the selected item. I know I need an event listener, but I'm confused as to what I should use to detect a change in selection in my list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add it to the JList object:

```
myJList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello you selected me!  "
            + dataList.getSelectedValue().toString());
    }
});
```